# Is the SUMO 0.28.0 and SUMO(0.28.0+dfsg1+7+20) are same?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

i wanted to install sumo 0.29.0(latest version) on Ubuntu 16.04. but when i'm installing according to the guidance provided in
http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing
it always installed giving following executions

please some one help me to solve this
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu repository is not always up to date and is still at 0.28.0. If you really need the most recent version (0.30.0 as of today), you will need to build from source as described in the SUMO wiki http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing/Linux_Build.